# LocalDate JPA repository strange "feature"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, localdate

Here is the RequestBody as JSON in SpringBoot RestController

```
{
    "birthdate": "1991-09-30"
}
```

Entity:

```
class MyEntity {
    private LocalDate birthdate;
}
```

JPA Repository:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {}
```

Saving entity:

```
myEntity.setBirthdate(LocalDate.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

Problem:
Working fine dates after `1991-09-30` and saved as it is. But dates before this are saved as one day before.
For example, dates before subtracting one day

```
{
    "birthdate": "1991-09-29"
}
```

[image]

PS.

I'm using `mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04:
[image]

Comment: Your database and your local timezone is the same ? Which database you are using ?

Comment: Mysql version 8

Comment: I am talking about the timezone of your application runs(JVM). What is your timezone  ?

Comment: I updated the question and put timezones of everything I use, pls check it out

Comment: And the strange thing is, why dates before `1991-09-29` is not working exactly?

Comment: Seems like your timezone  not matched, you can add timeone info in jdbc url like _...&serverTimezone=Asia/Tashkent&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false_ See here details https://www.baeldung.com/mysql-jdbc-timezone-spring-boot

Comment: @Eklavya it worked with your solution, I had to set my server timezone. Thank you, if you post your comment as an answer it would be helpful to others too)

Comment: However strange behaviour "dates before 1991-09-29 is not working exactly?"

Answer (score 0):

try using Date
this is just example :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name="birthdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthdate;
```